# TensorFlow/Keras code returns FileNotFoundError on Win10

Tags: python, windows, tensorflow, keras

I cannot understand what I missed.
My OS is Windows10, 64bit.

This is my code:

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_datasets as tfds
import os
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
import logging

logger = tf.get_logger()

logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)

_URL = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/cats_and_dogs_filtered.zip'

zip_dir = tf.keras.utils.get_file('cats_and_dogs_filterted.zip',origin=_URL,extract=True)

zip_dir_base = os.path.dirname(zip_dir)

base_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(zip_dir),'cats_and_dogs_filterted')
print(base_dir)

train_dir = os.path.join(base_dir,'train')

train_cats_dir = os.path.join(train_dir,'cats')

num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
```

This is its traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/USER/Desktop/PythonWorkspace/pythonProject1/tfu/fc3.py", line 31, in <module>
    num_cats_tr = len(os.listdir(train_cats_dir))
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Users\\USER\\.keras\\datasets\\cats_and_dogs_filterted\\train\\cats'
```

Answer (score 1):

Spelling.  ALWAYS double-check your spelling.  You have downloaded "cats_and_dogs_filtered" but your code is looking for "cats_and_dogs_filterted".  They're not the same.

When a name is long like this, put it in a constant so there's no change for error.

```
BASE = 'cats_and_dogs_filtered'
_URL = "https://storage.googleapis.com/mledu-datasets/"+BASE+".zip"
...
```